# SparkR: How to add business days (weekdays without weekends) to date

Tags: r, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, sparkr

I'am trying to add a specific number of business days(BD) to a date column in SparkDataFrmae.

```
      DATE_IN
1 2021-03-25
```

For example if old date is `2021-03-25` and we will add `2 BD` the new date will be `2021-03-29` and output should be :

```
      DATE_IN    DATE_OUT
1 2021-03-25   2021-03-29
```

I find solution to use iteration like in example of bellow :

```
DATEADD <- function(date_conv, increment){ 
          date_out <- date_conv

          for(i in 1:as.numeric(increment)){
           date_out <- ifelse(dayofweek(date_out) == (1 | 6),
                              date_add(date_out, 2),
                              ifelse(dayofweek(date_out) == 5,
                                     date_add(date_out,3),
                                     date_add(date_out,1)
                                     )
                              )
         }
return(date_out)
}

df <- df %>% withColumn("DATE_OUT", DATEADD(column("DATE_IN"),2))
head(df)
```

But this is very slowly and take a lot of GC memory

Exist a clearly and more elegant way to add of business days to date?

**NOTE:** Without `expr` because I trying to perform that sum into a function and date from input is a stand alone column without dataframe

Comment: What does this have to do with `SparkR`? As it looks you could just use the [bizdays](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/bizdays/) package.

Comment: ```date_conv```  is an S4 object (Column of a  SparkDataFrame) , i don't think ``bizdays``` is working with it